# qmake variables, difference of $$VAR and $${VAR}

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, qmake

For Qt qmake [variables](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-variable-reference.html) I sometimes see different notations.

Examples

```
$$PWD
$${PWD}
```

For me it seems to work the same, what is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#variables) the two notations are almost equivalent. The only difference is that `the second notation allows you to append the contents of the variable to another value without separating the two with a space`.

Comment: Good hint, somehow i have missed this. Thanks

Comment: The page behind that link says nothing about qmake, and I can't find a page "near" it in the graph of links that does.

Comment: @Jesdisciple Thank you very much for notifying me. Indeed, the link was no longer valid. I have replaced it.